# highlight selected grid row in jquery

Tags: jquery, coding-style

I am trying to highlight the selected row in a grid thru jquery.

```
    $('#myGrid tr').click(function() {
        $('#<%=imyGrid.ClientID%> tr').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");

    });
```

and I've edited jquery-ui.css [d/led and added locally inside styles folder of solution) as follows:

```
.selected{
background-color:Gray;}
```

but the click still doesn't highlight the row. I tried the same by created a nother website with an aspx page and it worked ok.

Comment: is it asp.net gridview you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you have another css rule defined that has a higher precedence than `.selected` if you want to override that precedence you can use `!important`

```
.selected{
  background-color:Gray !important;
}
```

Comment: Sounds plausible. Use something like firebug or any other code-inspector to see if the class is actually being assigned to the row.